# package development: setting options before dependencies load

Tags: r

My R package has a dependency that needs a certain option set before it loads. Setting this option in the `.onLoad` function of the **zzz.r** file of my package does not work, since the dependency appears to load before `.onLoad` is called.

How can I guarantee that a certain option is set for the user of my package before its dependencies load?

Here is a link to a sample package that illustrates the situation: [soExample.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8trcfz5scr60fk/soExample.zip?dl=0)

The dependency in my example is the **bartMachine** package. The setting in question controls the amount of memory available to Java. When I'm using **bartMachine** in interactive mode, I can simply set the option, load **bartMachine**, and the startup message informs me that it has recognized the `java.parameters` option I've set and made the requested amount of memory available to Java.

```
options(java.parameters='-Xmx5g')
library(bartMachine)
# ....
# Welcome to bartMachine v1.2.1! You have 4.77GB memory available.
```

However, when I load my package that depends on **bartMachine**, the `java.parameter` option set in `.onLoad` does not take effect in time and **bartMachine** makes only the default amount of memory available.

```
library(soExample)
# ....
# Welcome to bartMachine v1.2.1! You have 0.48GB memory available.
```

Comment: I've just found myself in a completely analogous situation, wishing for just the same thing. Since asking this question, have you learned some way of setting options before a package loads or attaches one of its Depends or Imports? (FTR: In my case, I'm wanting to set the option `exifr.exiftoolcommand`, which points to the location of the external executable exiftool, **before** my own package imports package **exifr**.)

Comment: Any solution how to deal with this in general and not specifically related to the `barMachine` package?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of the package and I never thought about this scenario. A few questions:

1. Can you ship your user (you?) a local package (in a tar.gz file)?
2. Do you need the ability to customize the amount of RAM still?

What I was thinking is: you clone the code, you call `options(java.parameters='-Xmx5g')` within the edited zzz.R after the jpackage on line 2 [here](https://github.com/kapelner/bartMachine/blob/master/bartMachine/R/zzz.R). You do `R CMD build bartMachine` to get a package, you send the package to the user and have them install locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The package is internal, so this might actually be feasible. I'm going to leave the question unanswered, since a workable solution for the mass-distribution scenario still escapes me.

Comment: Wait a minute: what prevents you from just running`options(java.parameters='-Xmx5g')` before you do anything at all?

Comment: That would of course ensure the right settings. My actual situation is one in which I'm deploying a package on several machines with the same resources and I'd like to fit as much of the R configuration into the package itself so that no matter how it is run on these machines, it will have the correct settings at load time. But the limitation is merely an inconvenience and by no means a deal breaker for using the package.

Comment: I believe all deployment with Java requires you to start a JVM with certain parameters and rJava implementations in CRAN packages are no exception.